# PHP - New to OOP, already stuck

Tags: php, oop

I am getting started with OOP because I already wrote procedural code enough that I want to step up.

I started by creating a file 'user.class.php', wrote some code, and loaded in into the server.

```
<?php

class user {

  private $name;
  private $age;

  function __construct($name, $age){
    $this->name=$name;
    $this->age=$age;
  }

  function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }
  function getAge() {
    return $this->age;
  }

}

$usr = new user('Alex', 16);

print($usr->getName.'<br>');
print($usr->getAge.'<br>');
```

I ran the code on the web server and got the following error:

```
 Notice: Undefined property: user::$getName in /Library/WebServer/Documents/user.class.php on line 24
```

Same happened with the getAge function call.

If I can get this code working I will feel better by starting to write more OO code instead of just procedural code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **getName** is an function/method. Use `$usr->getName()` instead of `$usr->getName`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just missing your parenthesis for your method calls. Without them you are trying to get a property called `getName` which doesn't exist:

```
print($usr->getName().'<br>');
print($usr->getAge().'<br>');
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Scrapped my comment lol

Comment: Wow! True true. I've been programming Java and didn't realize it is the exact same thing. Thank you so much and pardon my lack of skills when double reading code.

Answer (score 2):

`$usr->getName` means member variable
where you have a function so

```
$usr->getName()
```

is the correct way to call the function for that object

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parenthesis in 
    `print($usr->getName().'<br>');`